# What steps are required to complete upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

i am attempting to upgrade from 10.04 lts to 12.04.4 .
The download appears in download window,i would like direction on what to do next to finish the download / upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link as it this has already been answered before. [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)